# JQuery: Placement of document.ready function not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm newbie to JQuery and i am testing the document.ready function. I'm building a login page and the intention is upon login page loaded, I want the cursor to be placed (focus) on the 'Email Address' field.

The document.ready function code is simple as below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
                            document.getElementById("email").focus();
                            });
    </script>
```

I have tried putting this in the HEAD element and even at the end of the BODY element but I can't seem to get the cursor on that 'Email Address' page upon loading.

Here's the whole code (e.g. where I put the document.ready at the end of the BODY element).

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/goeasyhome_logo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/login.css" />
<script src="/javascript/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showerror(input) {
        if (document.getElementById("email").childNodes.item(0).value.length == 0) {
        input.setCustomValidity("Please fill out this field");
    } else {
        input.setCustomValidity("Please enter a valid email address");
    }

alert('x');
</script>
</head>

<body>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<header>
    <div id="header-center-11x12">
        <img id="goeasyhome_logo_12x12" src="/images/goeasyhome_basic.png"
            alt="goeasyhome" />
    </div>
</header>

<br />
<div id="main-content">
    <form method="post" action="j_security_check">
        <div id="email">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="j_username"
                pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}"
                oninvalid="showerror(this)" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')"
                required="required" />
        </div>
        <div id="password">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="j_password"
                required="required" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="signin">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <br /> <a class="passwdsignup-color" href="/forgotpassword.jsp">Forgot
        Password? </a> <a class="passwdsignup-color signup-position"
        href="/signup.jsp">Sign Up?</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById("email").focus();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: If you have a new question, post a new question, DO NOT edit this question. I'll vote to close it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are selecting by `id`:

```
document.getElementById("email")
```

...you need to put the `id` attribute on your input element:

```
<input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="j_username"
       pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}"
       oninvalid="showerror(this)" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')"
       required="required" />
```

Comment: @Jonanthan.Brink Thanks very much. I would like to ask another stupid question. Can you check it out on the main questionnaire? Thanks

Comment: @yapkm01 Not sure what you mean by "main questionnaire" but if you give your input tag an id it will be globally available.

Comment: @Jonanthan.Brink I just updated the questions again. Check the bottom. Thanks

Comment: @yapkm01 ah, I see. You would need to move your alert into the `$(document).ready` block. Otherwise it will be executed before your DOM is even loaded

Comment: @Jonanthan.Brink I see .. last question. Do you guys get paid if I check one of you guys as answer? LOL

Comment: @yapkm01 :) Please check the answer that was most helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery selectors, and target the actual input, not the div that encloses it:

```
$("#email input").focus()
```

You might want to read up on [jQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)